# Changing a cell in Excel 10 results in 00:00?

Tags: excel, time, hour, minute

I encountered a wierd behaviour while working with Excel 10:
Column B has "time in" in HH:MM format
Column C has "time out" in HH:MM format
I want column D to have the time difference displayed as decimal amount of hours (so if B4 has 10:00 and C4 has 13:30, D4 will have 3.5). I tried using

```
=HOUR(C4-B4)+MINUTE(C4-B4)/60
```

but that gives me 00:00
I then tried:

```
=HOUR(C4-B4)
```

which returns 3 for the above example, but when I tried adding minutes it went back to 00:00.
I now tried to remove the minutes part and returned to

```
=HOUR(C4-B4)
```

just as before, but now it returns 00:00 (for the exact same formula that returned 3 earlier). it only worked again when I used "undo" until I was back at the first try.
anything else I tried adding to that formula, even as simple as

```
=HOUR(C4-B4)+3
```

returned 00:00.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out every time I tried adding something to the formula, the cell's format went to "time", so having a number it didn't know what to do with, it displayed "00:00". the solution was to right-click the cell (D4)>format cells>general.